# Split String and then put in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I have a situation where images name for a particlar post are coming in a string:
like this:

```
**"i_name":"logo_v1_300px.png,logo_v1_140px.png,logo_v1_220px.png"**
```

I need to split this string and show like(html below):

```
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="images/photo2.png" alt=""></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="images/photo3.png" alt=""></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="images/photo4.png" alt=""></a></li> 
 </ul>
```

I have filter which splits string like:

```
  angular.module('myFilters', []).
  filter('split', function() {
   return function(input, delimiter) {
  var delimiter = delimiter || ',';

  return input.split(delimiter);
}
```

});

Now How can I show these images coming from split for a post:

```
 <div ng-repeat ="data in comments">

   mydata="{{data.text}}"

  photos
 <ul> 
   <li><a href="#"><img src="somepath"/{{data.i_name | split }}></a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

How can I accomplish this. How these images `(coming from split string filter)` can come under loop in Angular way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simplify your problem by performing the split inside a controller?

Controller:

```
var data = {
    "i_name":"logo_v1_300px.png,logo_v1_140px.png,logo_v1_220px.png"
};

$scope.images = data.i_name.split(',');
```

View:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="image in images">
        <a href="#"><img ng-src="somepath/{{image}}"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

why not:

```
ng-repeat="item in items.split(',')"
```

Comment: I did this and one deeper ... inside each item, text uses ng-bind=item.split('|')[0], url uses ng-bind=item.split('|')[1].   As long as there are only a few and not crazy amounts, the overhead should be minimal.  This way you can have:   foo|somepath/foo.jpg,bar|somepath/bar.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Well i did this in this way.

i had a large data coming in scope. It was not just about the image.There were nested objects data.

```
<div ng-repeat="image in data.image">
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="image in i_name | split ">
     <a href="#"><img ng-src="somepath/{{image}}"></a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```